# list of supported value in entity baseFieldDefinitions setDisplayOptions type(field widget)

Tags: 8, entities

I'm new in Drupal, I create my first entity and use baseFieldDefinitions to set fields and in fields I use setDisplayOptions to set form like this:

```
$fields['piece'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('integer')
  ->setLabel(t('piece'))
  ->setDisplayOptions('view', [
    'label' => 'hidden',
    'type' => 'string',
    'weight' => 2,
  ])
  ->setDisplayOptions('form', [
    'label' => 'inline',
    'type' => 'string',/////// what is supported value list of type key
    'weight' => 2,
  ])
  ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
  ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);
```

what is supported value list of type key in display option?

I only found `options_buttons` and `string`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What you are looking for are the *field widget plugins*, these depend on what modules you have installed.

Use *Drupal Console* to run this command:

```
drupal debug:plugin field.widget
```

This is what I have on a local site with some contrib modules:

```
 -------------------------------------------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
  Plugin ID                                    Plugin class                                                                           
 -------------------------------------------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
  boolean_checkbox                             Drupal\Core\Field\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget\BooleanCheckboxWidget                       
  datetime_datelist                            Drupal\datetime\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget\DateTimeDatelistWidget                        
  datetime_default                             Drupal\datetime\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget\DateTimeDefaultWidget                         
  datetime_timestamp                           Drupal\Core\Datetime\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget\TimestampDatetimeWidget                  
  email_default                                Drupal\Core\Field\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget\EmailDefaultWidget                          
  entity_reference_autocomplete                Drupal\Core\Field\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget\EntityReferenceAutocompleteWidget           
  entity_reference_autocomplete_tags           Drupal\Core\Field\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget\EntityReferenceAutocompleteTagsWidget       
  field_example_3text                          Drupal\field_example\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget\Text3Widget                              
  field_example_colorpicker                    Drupal\field_example\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget\ColorPickerWidget                        
  field_example_text                           Drupal\field_example\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget\TextWidget                               
  field_permission_example_widget              Drupal\field_permission_example\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget\TextWidget                    
  file_generic                                 Drupal\file\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget\FileWidget                                        
  image_image                                  Drupal\image\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget\ImageWidget                                      
  language_select                              Drupal\Core\Field\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget\LanguageSelectWidget                        
  link_default                                 Drupal\link\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget\LinkWidget                                        
  menu_item_extras_view_mode_selector_select   Drupal\menu_item_extras\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget\MenuItemExtrasViewModeSelectorSelect  
  moderation_state_default                     Drupal\content_moderation\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget\ModerationStateWidget               
  number                                       Drupal\Core\Field\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget\NumberWidget                                
  oembed_textfield                             Drupal\media\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget\OEmbedWidget                                     
  options_buttons                              Drupal\Core\Field\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget\OptionsButtonsWidget                        
  options_select                               Drupal\Core\Field\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget\OptionsSelectWidget                         
  path                                         Drupal\path\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget\PathWidget                                        
  string_textarea                              Drupal\Core\Field\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget\StringTextareaWidget                        
  string_textfield                             Drupal\Core\Field\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget\StringTextfieldWidget                       
  text_textarea                                Drupal\text\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget\TextareaWidget                                    
  text_textarea_with_summary                   Drupal\text\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget\TextareaWithSummaryWidget                         
  text_textfield                               Drupal\text\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget\TextfieldWidget                                   
  uri                                          Drupal\Core\Field\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget\UriWidget                                   
 -------------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I use your command: drupal debug:plugin field.widget

                                                                                                                        
 [ERROR] Command "debug:plugin", is not a valid command name.

Comment: Do you have the latest stable version?
. I have Drupal 8.6, Drupal Console version 1.8.0 and PHP 7.1.20.
This is the command documentation https://hechoendrupal.gitbooks.io/drupal-console/en/commands/debug-plugin.html

Comment: If you don't have time to debug the issue, you could use the Plugin Class Package to know what module a given plugin belongs to.

Comment: sry my fault. my apache not running.it's work

Answer (score 2):

Would like to add that if you want to get list of baseFieldDefinitions available on your installation run

```
drupal debug:plugin field.field_type
```

and to get huge list of formatters, run this

```
drupal debug:plugin field.formatter
```